# Install NetLogo on Raspberry Pi 2B - Advice

Tags: pi-2

I would like to run NetLogo on my Raspberry Pi 2 model B. 
I have downloaded the NetLogo tar.bz on to my system.

/home/pi/downloads/NetLogo-5.3.1-32.tgz

And I have extracted it there.
It doesn't run by clicking on the executable nor from the command line.

sudo apt-get update (& upgrade) is up to date as of this week.
Would you please tell me what to do next?

Many thanks
Scriptham

Answer (score 2):

The file you have downloaded is an archive, not an executable. You should unpack it with fileroller or a similar tool and run `netlogo.sh`.

Note that NetLogo needs Java to run. NetLogo comes with Java bundled in, but that version is most probably x86 only. You'll have to install Java package provided by Raspbian:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-jre
```